# When closing forms close how to close all opened MessageBoxes

Tags: c#

I close form with `form.Dispose()` but i have problem that all opened MessageBoxes does not close. They are still opened. How to close all MessageBoxes when closing form? Is this possible?

I am using compact framework 3.5

Comment: The best way to get rid of a message box is by not calling its Show() method.  Use *very* sparingly.  If you do have to show one then automatically closing it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible. MessageBox wraps the `user32.MessageBox` API, which blocks the thread that it is called on until the user responds. They're designed to be modal and you'd have to kill your process to close them.

You could write your own MessageBox implementation using forms, and use ShowDialog to make them modal. That way you could close them yourself.